# What do you call an unclear video or television image (in other words, a bad quality video)?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want a single word to describe a video or TV image that is not very clear (not necessarily blurry or pixelated). Just a video footage or image that is bad quality. Sentence example:

*I cannot see what's going on in this video clearly. The video is very [insert word].*

"Unclear" may be the right word here, but I find it too vague and broad in this case. To me, "unclear" can also describe unclear texts, ideas and other notions. Doesn't seem fit to me. Is there a more appropriate contender here?

Comment: A quick look for synonyms of 'poor quality' at [WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/poor-quality.html) gives _grainy fuzzy blurry distorted blurred bleary unclear unfocused foggy gauzy indistinct muzzy vague ill-defined low resolution low quality lacking definition poor quality_. Research is important on ELU.

Comment: "low quality" is the usual expression, if you google or look on video forums. There are more specific terms like grainy, low-res, blurry, blocky, noisy, corrupt, artefacted/ual/y, dark, etc, but "low quality" is the more general term.

Comment: I would probably say "fuzzy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about ***fuzzy***?

> ADJECTIVE
> A fuzzy picture, image, or sound is unclear and hard to see or hear.
>
> ([Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fuzzy))

> : lacking in clarity or definition
> // *moving the camera causes fuzzy photos*
>
> ([Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fuzzy))

> I cannot see what's going on in this video clearly. The video is very *fuzzy*<sup>[1](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22The+video+is+very+fuzzy.%22)</sup> <sup>[2](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22fuzzy+video+quality%22)</sup>.

Comment: Yep. That seems to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: @E.Groeg: If you found my answer helpful, feel free to accept this answer (click on the grey tick next to this answer) to give closure to your question.

Answer (score 2):

**As you require a word that suits the sentence,**

I cannot see what's going on in this video clearly.
The video is very [insert word].

**The video is very incoherent*, as it's inconsistent to express what needed to be.

or, Would you like to use 'muddle'?
I can't see what's going on it as it's a muddled display.

or,
The video is very substandard [in the sense, poor in quality]
similarly, You could use 'atrocious'. - bad in quality.*

**If the answers are not up to your expectation, I would like to bring up changes in the future.**

Answer (score 2):

> I cannot see what's going on in this video clearly. It's too **low-grade**.

For a single word that means *poor quality* for any reason, e.g., low resolution, poor lighting or focus, interference, pixelation, degraded or antiquated media (videotape, kinescope), or glitches, I suggest

> **low-grade**  (adj.)
>
> Of low or inferior quality. (OED)

---

> The different external factors like low lighting conditions,
> **low-grade video quality**, distance motion, and occlusion also affect the detection and recognition system. [Y. Zhang et al.; *Smart
> Trends in Computing and Communications*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Smart_Trends_in_Computing_and_Communicat/NW9KEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=low-grade%20video&pg=PA542&printsec=frontcover) (2021)

> Playing in parallel to this story are **low-grade video images** of
> rural Lebanon and a music track of singing and percussion. [J. Haladyn
> and M. Jordan; *The Films and Videos of Jamelie Hassan*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Films_and_Videos_of_Jamelie_Hassan_D/i1tfAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=low-grade%20video&pg=PA22&printsec=frontcover) (2010)

Answer (score 2):

Poor quality images which are not actually blurred or pixelated might be *grainy*. Film contains *grains* of emulsion, which can react unevenly, particularly where the light level is too low for the speed of the film. The term can be applied to more modern media including analogue television where signal noise disrupts the image.

[image: Grainy image]

Blurring and pixellation are definitely different:

[image: Blurred image] [image: Pixellated image]

Image via [pxhere.com](https://pxhere.com/en/photo/634757)

Comment: But what if it's not grainy?

Comment: @E.Groeg Then you don't use that word. Your question is hardly specific.

Comment: Just because you can't write your own answers properly doesn't mean you should throw it on my question. Your answer was like apples to oranges. Unclearness doesn't always pertain to graininess.

Answer (score 1):

"Low resolution"  or "low res".

The image is too low-res to make out the details.
The image doesn't have a high enough resolution to make out the details.

[image resolution.](https://smartframe.io/blog/what-is-image-resolution-everything-you-need-to-know/)

Answer (score 0):

I've mostly heard the word '***noisy***' in this context. Heard, or maybe used, which is hardly a qualification.

Nevertheless, consider the [signal-to-noise ratio](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/signal-to-noise-ratio):

> the ratio of one parameter, such as power of a wanted signal to the same parameter of the noise at a specified point in an electronic circuit, etc.

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio) puts it:

> Signal-to-noise ratio (SNR or S/N) is a measure used in science and engineering that compares the level of a desired signal to the level of background noise.

While this is indeed technical terminology, the visualization of something 'noisy' is straightforward, and I believe everyone will get the meaning:

> "*I cannot see what's going on in this video clearly. The video is very noisy.*"

'[Noisy](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/noisy)' itself can be defined as:

> characterized by much [noise](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/noise):
>
> i.e.
>
> 5. an electric disturbance in a communications system that interferes with or prevents reception of a signal or of information, as the buzz on a telephone or snow on a television screen.

When "bad" video is due to it being a bad recording, e.g. a recording made in low-light conditions, in which case the signal-to-noise ratio and the given definition of 'noisy' do not truly apply, a more generic term like '*low quality*' or '*low-grade*', as given by [DjinTonic](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/585255/326523), could be preferable.